# How to set the elevation of a Vuetify 2 expansion panel

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do you set the elevation to 0 (remove the box-shadow) for expansion panels in Vuetify v2?

Comment: The elevation helper class doesn't work for expansion panels in v2. I tried also changing the css by adding "box-shadow: none" to v-expansion-panels, v-expansion-panel, v-expansion-panel-content but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

So the Vuetify v2 elevation helper class doesn't work on expansion panels.

In the end I had to add the following CSS to my component to remove the box-shadow/elevation from the expansion panel:

```
.v-expansion-panel::before {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the elevation maybe what you need is to add the `flat` property, this prop removes the expansion-panel’s elevation and borders

You can learn more about the expansion panels props in [v-expansion-panels API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panels/#props) (Vuetify version 2.4)

Also, if you still want lines between the expansion panels
you can add the element: `<v-divider class="m-0"></v-divider>` between each panel
see more about the structure of the expansion panels in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#usage)
by clicking in the `view source` tab with the icon `< >`

Comment: This should absolutely be the correct answer. That said, Vuetify should be more consistent about this. They've setup elevation to be the answer for any box shadows like this, but in this specific case, you have to look for something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `elevation` prop to "0" for `<v-expansion-panel>`

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panel/#props-elevation

```js
<v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel elevation="0" v-for="i in 3" :key="i" title="Item"
        text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"></v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

Comment: The `elevation` property does not exist in the `v-expansion-panel` component for Vuetify 2, which is the version OP asked